# Euclid's definition of a prime

Tags: prime-numbers, math-history

In Euclid's Elements, Book VII, Definition 11, Euclid states that

> A prime number is that which is measured by a unit alone.

As I understand it, this means that a prime number's only divisor is 1. Obviously the modern definition is that a prime number's only divisors are 1 and itself.

This is a semantic difference I know, but what part about Euclid's definition am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think Euclid is assuming "measures" only applies to the smaller of two unequal numbers in regards to the larger.  i.e. a number doesn't measure itself, a larger number can not measure a smaller.  A number can only measure a larger number, and a number can only be measured by a smaller number.

Comment: For "measured" read "properly divisible".

Comment: Or when you say "a prime number's only divisor is 1" Euclid is defining that a "divisor" which he refers to by the verb "measures" most be strictly less than the number.

Comment: Euclid's book 1 stipulates that the whole is **greater** than the part, so a number cannot be part of itself and hence (presumably) can't measure itself. These days we find it more convenient to think of a quantity as a part of itself: we are happy with $3 - 3 = 0$, but the Greeks didn't have a concept of $0$ as a number.